# How to filter outliers in a set of data?

Tags: python, filter, filtering

I'm trying to filter the data as shown in the first image. There are outliers that are occurring periodically. What is the best way to filter those outliers? I want to have a set of data as shown on the second picture.

My goal is to fit this data after filtering with a polynomial.

Is there a way to do this without a lot of effort in python? If not, a hint towards the right algorithm would be great.

Data with marked outliers:
[image: Data with marked outliers]

Goal:
[image: Goal]

Comment: Do you already have the polynomial?

Comment: No, this is just data that I got from a measurement.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a polynomial regression using scikit-learn.  Make sure to created enough features so you get a fit line that looks good on observation.  Once you have that polynomial, then I would think it would be simple to find the outliers by finding their distance to the polynomial function and setting a threshold.